# Downloading my programs data from a webserver (Its basically just a .exe turned into .txt) but when I put it into a .exe it does not run?

Tags: c++, file, metadata, executable, file-storage

So currently I am using a basic Http request to pull the exe data from my server weblink.com/Program.exe
it returns my program in .txt form but when I put it into a file it will not run.
I assume this is because I need metadata but have no clue how to find that process or even how to google something as specific as that... So I am either asking for a solution (how to add proper .exe metadata) or if there is a better way to download files like that in C++

*Note I **cannot** use basic windows functions such as DownloadToFileA or External Library's (Like LibCurl/Curl)

```
OutFile.open(XorStr("C:\\Users\\Program.exe").c_str(), std::ios::out);
if (OutFile.is_open())
{
     OutFile << Output;
     //Initialize .exe Meta Data???  
}
OutFile.close();
```

Comment: Turned into .txt why? and how? and turned back into binary how?

Comment: If you turn a .exe into .txt it becomes just a bunch of data, that's whats outputting from the http request

Comment: It already is a 'bunch of data'. What exactly do you mean by 'turn a .exe into .txt'? And secondly, what is `Output`? You haven't provided nearly enough information here.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/728b77539df07688d9f429122ee3e434 - Thats my program...              https://gyazo.com/a65a41dbb756a62ef260bd9e8f818c4a - Turned into a .txt                  https://gyazo.com/7899f1a80fb0b546631e3624aad607ee - The resulting data                  this is whats returned, and also why it has been so hard to find answers on google about my situation

Comment: Nobody, least of all me, is going to follow links. Code or text that forms part of a question must be posted *in the question,* and NB *as text*, not as images.

Comment: Here is my exact problem... No one understands the question at hand (or clearly is willing too). My issue I'm sure would be much more obvious if you actually knew what I was trying to say...

Comment: I agree. Nobody understands your question. Why? Because you haven't stated it sufficiently. For example, I broke the habit of a lifetime and followed your links, and all I found there was two directory listings and a 'bunch of data'. This tells us exactly nothing: and, specifically, it doesn't answer any of the questions *I* have asked *you.*

Comment: The problem I mention was that I did not know how to phrase it... I have no idea what that data inside of exe's is called... Its not bytes or any other form of information represented as text that I know of, sorry.

Comment: The problem is that you made a number of claims that weren't true, and that you didn't answer any of the questions you were asked about them. You said the data was converted from .exe to .txt, which it wasn't; you claimed that the problem was missing metadata, which it wasn't; and you didn't state what `Output` was, despite having specifically been asked; and instead of providing useful information you just provided directory listings and a 'bunch of data'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open your file in binary mode otherwise newline translation will screw up your executable:

```
OutFile.open(XorStr("C:\\Users\\Program.exe").c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
```

Comment: @YoAvrageBiTz So there was no 'turn into .txt' process at all. The data already arrived at your client correctly.